# Select all objects with the same color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, print-production

I have an .ai file of a label. It has various shades of green in its design. I want to replace all objects with that color and change it to a new color.

So if I pick #d0d0d0 and want to replace it with #f0f0f0, I pick an area of the first color, and it changes all #d0d0d0 in the document to #f0f0f0?

Comment: Are you changing all the various shades to one color, or are you asking how to select 1 shade but select all objects in the document with that shade and change them all at the same time?

Comment: @AndrewH the latter; if I select one specific red, I want to change all of that red to blue for example. Only that exact color.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Choose an object then simply go to 'Select → Same → Fill color' and this will select everything in that fill color. Note this only works for the exact same color code, it will not work for similar shades using slightly different color codes.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting the artwork

**Menu Edit** > **Edit Colors** > **Recolor Artwork** or click this icon on the Top Options Menu: [image: recolor]

Double click the color to change > Select the new color or type a new Hex Number

[image: recolor]

Comment: While this may not answer the OP question, it certainly addresses the purpose of the question. Thanks, I was looking for this exact solution!